# Relational Database Design Understanding

Tags: database-design, relational-database

For the relation

```
R(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
```

The folloing functional dependences hold,

```
D -> G, B
E -> A
B -> G, E, C
A -> F, C
```

Use inference rules to find the minimal basis and determine the key of the relation.

Would I be correct is saying that D is the key of the relation? And I am assuming that this is not a BCNF relation.

Comment: And what is the concrete problem that you have with this exercise?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add what I thought my answer is to this, oops! I was wondering if it were correct.

Comment: I'm not up on the notation you're using, but the definition of a primary key is that everything else in the tuple depends on it, and it doesn't depend on anything in the tuple. If the items on the right of -> depend on or are 'owned' by the item on the left, then there is indeed only one item which is only on the left and not the right and which all the others are eventually owned by.

Answer (score 2):

D is the only candidate key.

R(A, B, C, D, E, F, G) is not in 3NF, because there are transitive dependencies. If it's not in 3NF, it can't be in BCNF.